GitHub Actions Error: unable to start container process - node16_alpine/bin/node
We are facing a GitHub actions build error, which is impacting merging PRs to main. The error:

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/__e/node16_alpine/bin/node": stat /__e/node16_alpine/bin/node: no such file or directory: unknown

It isn't perfectly clear why this issue arises today on Nov 13, 2024, but we have learned that:

GitHub Actions are transitioning away from node 16 to 20 - September 2023

Thoughts?

We learned that:

Cache action V4 uses Node 20 - Jan 2024

For upgrading actions/cache to v4 works.
uses: actions/cache@v4

It remains unclear, on why this occured today in Nov 2024.
